# Redirect domain

Tags: dns, redirect

I noticed that Google somehow indexed my site but with incorrect subdomain. Instead of putting a link to www.mydomain.com or mydomain.com it shows ns1.mydomain.com and ns2.mydomain.com, which results in broken images, because I used relative paths.

Now, I don't even have ns1 and ns2 setup as subdomains. I have those in my DNS settings.

So, how do I go about redirecting users to the correct address?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I was able to fix this by placing this into my .htaccess file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ns1.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
```

But even though I fixed it, I am very curious how did Google index those links anyway?

Comment: Or better RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

Comment: Great suggestion! Thanks. I just had to add h ttp://www. before mydomain.com/$1 [R=permanent,L] Note space after "h", used here only to prevent from converting into link.